# UITextView tap event to set an UITableView visible

Tags: swift, uitableview, events, uitextview

I'm working on a swift application,

Let's say, I have a simple `UITextView` and I want, If the user tap on it, open a `UITableView`.

How I imagine the thing, is to make an `UITableView` set as `invisible` and when we tap the `UITextView`, the `UITableView` becomes `visible`. and when we tap a button on a `custom cell` of the `UITableView`, the `UITableView` becomes invisible again and the `UITextView` text get what was on the cell.

Is it just possible? I mean, the only `Received Actions` available on a UITextView is copy, cut, paste... Nothing like `Touch Down`, `On Click` or something like this..

I don't succeed to find informations about this on swift, if somebody already tried something like this?

Thanks in advance. Regards,

fselva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Editing did began action like shown in below image:

[image]

By creating this method when user tap on textField that method will call and into that method you can show your tableView as shown below:

```
@IBAction func editingBegan(sender: AnyObject) {
    table.hidden = false
}
```

After that if you want to hide `tableView` when user press button on custom cell then just create a action for that button in your custom cell class and you can hide `tableView`.